# Highcharter tooltip not working with many series

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to create a line chart with many series (more than 50) using the `highcharter` package in R.
When I use fewer series (less than 40) my tooltip works correctly, but when the number of series increase, the tooltip stops displaying the category of the x-axis and starts simply counting from zero to the number of ticks. Here is the code to reproduce:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

test1<-data.frame(Value=rnorm(300,0,1),Type=rep(c('A','B','C'),each=100),Period=rep(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),as.Date('2020-04-09'),by=1),3))
test2<-data.frame(Value=rnorm(500,0,1),Type=rep(as.character(1:50),each=10),Period=rep(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),as.Date('2020-01-10'),by=1),50))

category1<-unique(format(test1$Period,'%d/%b/%y'))
category2<-unique(format(test2$Period,'%d/%b/%y'))

hchart(test1,type='line',hcaes(x=as.character(Period),y=Value,group=Type)) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type='category',categories=as.list(category1),title='',labels=list(rotation=-30)) %>%
  hc_legend(align='left',maxHeight=100) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(line=list(marker=list(enabled=F))) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(shared=T,
             formatter=JS("function() {
                 var s = '';
                 
                 $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                 
                 if (point.y !== 0) {
                 s += '<br><b>'+ point.series.name +': </b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y,2,',','.');
                 }
                 
                 });
                 
                 return this.x + s;
                 }"))

hchart(test2,type='line',hcaes(x=as.character(Period),y=Value,group=Type)) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type='category',categories=as.list(category2),title='',labels=list(rotation=-30)) %>%
  hc_legend(align='left',maxHeight=100) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(line=list(marker=list(enabled=F))) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(shared=T,
             formatter=JS("function() {
                 var s = '';
                 
                 $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                 
                 if (point.y !== 0) {
                 s += '<br><b>'+ point.series.name +': </b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y,2,',','.');
                 }
                 
                 });
                 
                 return this.x + s;
                 }"))
```

And here are the outputs:

[image: chart1]

[image: chart2]

I don't know if this is a limitation because of the volume of information, but it is a strange behavior that I could not solve.

Comment: Have you tested how it works in regular JS?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge of JS, so no...